# Example 3, Sec. 28, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How does $S_\Omega$ satisfy the sequence lemma?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Here's the sequence lemma:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, let $x \in X$, and let $A \subset X$. If there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$, then $x \in \overline{A}$. Conversely, if $X$ is metrizable and if $x \in \overline{A}$, then there is a sequence of points of $A$ converging to $x$.

Then how to show that the minimal uncountable well-ordered set $S_\Omega$ satisfies the sequence lamma?

Here's how $S_\Omega$ evolves:

> Let $B$ be any uncountable well-ordered set, and let $C \colon= \{1, 2 \} \times B$ in the dictionary order. Then the set $C$ is well-ordered. Let $C_0$ be the subset of $C$ consisting of those elements $a$ of $C$ by which the section $S_a$ of $C$ is uncountable. For any $a \in C$, we define $S_a$ as follows: $$S_a \colon= \{ \ x \in C \ \colon \ x < a \ \}.$$ Then $C_0$ is non-empty. In fact, any element of the form $2 \times b$, where $b \in B$, belongs to $C_0$. So $C_0$ has a smallest element $\Omega$. Thus, $S_\Omega$ is uncountable, but for any element $a$ of $S_\Omega$, the section $S_a$ is countable. The topologies on $S_\Omega$ or $\overline{S_\Omega}$ are the respective subspace topologies these inherit as subsets of the set $C$, or their respective order topologies.

Also, $\Omega$ is a limit point of $S_\Omega$, but there is no sequence in $S_\Omega$ that converges to $\Omega$; in fact, any countable subset of $S_\Omega$ has an upper bound in $S_\Omega$. Thus, $\overline{S_\Omega} = S_\Omega \cup \{ \Omega \}$ does not satisfy the sequence lemma.

PS:

My Attempt:

> Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $S_\Omega$, and let $p \in S_\Omega$ be an adherent point of set $A$. We need to show that there exists a sequence $\left(p_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  in $S_\Omega$ that converges to point $p$.
>
> If $p \in A$, then we can take $p_n \colon= p$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we are done. So let us suppose that $p \not\in A$. Then $p$ is of course a limit point of $A$.

What next? How then can we construct a sequence $\left( p_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ that converges to $p$?

Comment: Where it says $S_x$, that should be $S_a$? Also, you should perhaps state the topology on $S_\Omega$.

Comment: It seems that the spaces you describe are commonly denoted $\omega_1=[0,\omega_1)$ and $\omega_1+1=[0,\omega_1]$. See, for example, [this blog post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/). The space $\omega_1$ is [first countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space), Therefore it is also [Frechet-Urysohn space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr.C3.A9chet.E2.80.93Urysohn_space), i.e. it "satisfies the sequence lemma".

Comment: @joriki, please see my latest edit.

Comment: @MartinSleziak can you please have a look at my post now? I have just edited it to include my attempt.

Comment: @joriki can you please have a look at my post now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a\in S_\Omega$. Then $S_a$ is countable, so $\{a\}\cup S_a$ is countable, and $S_\Omega\setminus(\{a\}\cup S_a)$ is uncountable and therefore non-empty. $S_\Omega$ is well-ordered, so $S_\Omega\setminus(\{a\}\cup S_a)$ has a least element; call it $a^+$. Suppose that $U$ is an open nbhd of $a$ in $S_\Omega$.

Case 1. Suppose first that this $a$ is NOT the smallest element of $S_\Omega$.

Then by definition there are $b,c\in S_\Omega$ such that $a\in(b,c)\subseteq U$, where $(b,c)=\{x\in S_\Omega:b<x<c\}$. Clearly $a<c$, so $a^+\le c$, and

$$a\in(b,a^+)\subseteq(b,c)\subseteq U\;.$$

Thus, $\mathscr{B}_a=\{(b,a^+):b\in S_a\}$ is a local base at $a$, and since $S_a$ is countable, so is $\mathscr{B}_a$.

Case 2. Next, suppose that $a$ is the smallest element of $S_\Omega$. Then there exists an element $c \in S_\Omega$ such that $a \in [a, c) \subset U$. Thus we again have $a^+ \leq c$, and so $a \in \left[a, a^+ \right) \subset [a, c) \subset U$.

Therefore we have the following as a local base at $a$:
$$ \mathscr{B}_a = \left\{ \ \left[ a, a^+ \right) \ \right\}. $$

This shows that $S_\Omega$ is first countable. The desired result now follows from the following lemma.

> **Lemma.** If $X$ is a first countable space, $x\in X$, $A\subseteq X$, and $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, then there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$.
>
> **Sketch of Proof.** Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable local base at $x$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=\bigcap_{k\le n}B_k$; $U_n$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so there is a point $x_n\in U_n\cap A$. Now check that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$. $\dashv$

Comment: your answers are so illuminating and insightful! But there's one thing I would like to ask: Which textbook (in terms of sequence of topics, notation, and terminology) do you follow in your answers to my questions on general topology? This I ask because your answers often use notation as well as notions that are different from those that Munkres talks about. Although I do manage to comprehend your answers, but only after some effort.

Comment: @Saaqib: I don’t follow any particular text. I generally use the notation to which I’m accustomed, which is an amalgamation derived from grad school experience and from reading many papers over the years, occasionally with small modifications when I think that something that I’d normally write is especially likely to cause difficulty. I use whatever notions seem to me simplest or most illuminating in the given context at the moment when I’m writing. (If I were still teaching and had the chance to teach a topology course, I probably wouldn’t use any book: I’d write up handouts.)

Comment: can you please have a look at my post now? I would be really grateful if you could enable me to complete the argument I've started in the PS!

Comment: what if $a$ is the smallest element of $S_\Omega$? Your proof as it is doesn't seem to account for the fact that the element $a$ _can_ be the smallest element of $S_\Omega$. So can you please modify your proof appropriately so that this case be also duly accounted for?

Comment: can we also give a more direct proof _without_ using first countability?

Comment: I've just edited your answer. Do you approve of the modifications I've made?